# signing into the wifi router using python

Tags: python, python-requests, wifi, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a script that would let me interact with my router without opening the browser. the first step is to obviously login and this is my code

```
import requests
login = {'userName':'data','pcPassword':'password'}
s = requests.Session()
s.post('http://192.168.1.2/',data=login)
```

and the output that I get is `<response[200]>` can someone tell me what it means? I tried googling it and got no reasonable answer back. the `userName` and `pcPassword` are the tags id I got after getting the page source. I am trying to get the contents of the next page after logging in and I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Requests returns a response object for each request.  Your `s.post` is a request to post data to the url.  The `<response [200]>` (which stands for successful request) is the representation of the response object.  What you are likely looking for is the `content` property of the response.

```
response = s.post(url, data=login)
print(response.content)
```

Requests responses contain a lot of useful data (content, original request, headers, etc).  I would suggest reading the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Can you please mark it as answered so people don't think the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly you are trying to do but I believe  means that the post request was successful. Giving an 'OK' html 200 error code back.

I know this probably doesn't help. Maybe you can clarify the question a bit more? What were you expecting? What are you intending to do with this code?

Comment: I am trying to get the contents of the next page after logging into the router. I am confused how to do that? @deancoakley